# No pasa del login a mi pagina principal

Tags: angular, ionic

En la versión lanzada con ionic serve funciona perfectamente.

Cuando lo pruebo en el móvil, no me carga la pantalla. Para cambiar de pantalla del login a la otra utilizo :

this.router.navigateByUrl('/app/tabs/paginaprincipal');

Por último al tener activada la consola por cable me ha lanzado la siguiente excepción después de mucho rato y se ha pausado en el debugger de chrome :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dáis alguna pista o idea de por donde pueden ir los tiros, o como depurar este error. La verdad que me es curioso, porque a priori está todo bien.

Código de la pantalla que debería de cargar:

```
@Component({
selector: 'miprincipal',
templateUrl: 'miprincipal.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./miprincipal.component.scss']
})
export class Miprincipal{

 @ViewChild('slider', { static: true }) private slider: IonSlides;

 // Atributos
 public ....

 // CONSTRUCTOR
 constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController,
  public tool: ToolService,
  private platform: Platform,
  public login: LoginService,
  public global: GlobalService,
  public router: Router) {
  this.login.isLogin();
 }

 ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
  this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(1, () => {
    this.tool.presentAlertConfirm();
  });
  this.erSlides.getActiveIndex()
    .then((pCurrentSlide: number) => this.currentSlideIndex = pCurrentSlide)
    .then(() => 
   this.login.conversacionEscuchar.setCARGAR(SELECCION, 
   InboxSubmodeEnum.ALL))
   .then(() => this.conversacion());

    }
```

Comment: Necesitaría que adjuntes el código que utilizas para realizar la navegación una vez logueado.

Comment: El código que utilizo para pasar es el router que he puesto en la pregunta. Después lo que carga en la pantalla te lo muestro arriba

Comment: Finalmente lo he solucionado con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308558/controlar-return-y-promesa