# Controlar return y promesa

Tags: angular, ionic

os muestro el ejemplo. Tengo esto:

```
tarea(){
 this.seleccionarApi();
 return this.cliente.sesion.login(usuario, pass)
}
```

La seleccionarApi llama a esto

```
 seleccionarApi() {
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
   this.storage.get('depuracion').then(valor => {
      //valores devueltos
   });
 }
}
```

La seleccionarApi tiene una promesa que se ejecuta dentro para hacer otras tareas. Me gustaría que no hiciera el return hasta que acabara la función. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo esperar?

Comment: Si tiene un `then` no es un observable, es una Promesa, no es lo mismo.

Comment: Vale, he actualizado la pregunta, es una promesa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer en ese caso es que tu función seleccionarApi devuelva una nueva promesa y sea en tu función tarea donde la resuelvas con then. Podría quedar de esta forma:

```
tarea(){
   this.seleccionarApi()
   .then( valores => {
     return this.cliente.sesion.login(usuario, pass);
   })
   .catch(error => { console.log('error: ', error) });
}
```

Entonces tu función seleccionarApi quedaría así:

```
seleccionarApi() {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.storage.get('depuracion').then(valor => {
        //valores devueltos
        resolve(valor);
      });
    }else {
      reject(null);
    }
  });
}
```

Por otro lado, puedes devolver directamente la promesa que te devuelve la función get de la siguiente forma y seguir recogiéndola en tu función tarea:

```
seleccionarApi() {
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
   return this.storage.get('depuracion');
 }
}
```

De las dos formas que te comento, tu función seleccionarApi devuelve una promesa y la capturas en la función tarea para que sea esta función la que espere a que se resuelva la promesa.

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Gracias , me ha servido muchísimo, es lo correcto lo que comentas :)